# Calculate Base Factorial

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How could I function named **unfactorial** that takes a number and returns a string representing it's base factorial in the form: `n!`? This would result in the un-do the factorial operation if one is possible. It should return *null* if no factorial was possible.

Package
A factorial operation looks like this:

> 5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120

#### Function Output:

```
unfactorial(120) // '5!'
unfactorial(150) // null
unfactorial(5040) // '7!'
```

#### My current Solution

```
    const unfactorial = (num) => {
      let d = 1
      while (num > 1 && Math.round(num === num)) {
        d += 1
        num /= d
      }
      if (num === 1)
        return `${d}!`
      else return null
    }
```

Comment: Is this a question or a task? Have you tried anything? (This reads like a code golf challenge, not a question)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you read the page [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?? If not, please do, and then create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is off topic about this question?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it using an auxiliary recursive function.

Note, it will not work for numbers that are not actual factorials. This is left as an exercise for the asker.

```js
const unfactorial = x => {
  const aux = (acc, x) => {
    if (x === 1)
      return acc - 1
    else
      return aux(acc + 1, x / acc)
  }
  return aux(2, x)
}

console.log(unfactorial(120))  // 5
console.log(unfactorial(5040)) // 7
```

**How it works**

Starting with the input number `x` and a counter, `acc = 2`, successively divide `x` by `acc` (then `acc + 1`, then `acc + 2`, etc) until `x == 1`. Then return `acc - 1`.

---

Or go bananas using only expressions. You'll probably like this, @Mr.Polywhirl

```js
const U = f => f (f)

const Y = U (h => f => f (x => h (h) (f) (x)))

const unfactorial = Y (f => acc => x =>
  x === 1 ? acc - 1 : f (acc + 1) (x / acc)
) (2)

console.log(unfactorial(120))  // 5
console.log(unfactorial(5040)) // 7
```

Comment: Please don't reward questions that don't have any evidence of attempting to solve the issue or research with an answer.

Comment: If you're gonna shorthand it, at lease use a one-liner. `const aux = (acc, n) => acc === 1 ? n - 1 : aux(acc / n, n + 1);` ;)

Comment: *"If you're going to shorthand it"* – yeah that's fine, but i think this is just a little more legible

Comment: The biggest issue I'm having is dealing numbers that do not have factorials. I am unsure of what to check for since they error with a maximum call stack, rather than NaN or null.

Comment: @MichaelFriedman well think about it for a little while. Looking at my code above, what is the first sign we can look for to spot a nonfactorial? Hint: observe `x` in `aux` as the computation runs